# place CSS Div elements side-by-side during overflow

Tags: html, css

I have two divs which I would like to put next to each other. One is simply a large div containing a few letters, and the other is made up of smaller divs containing text. When the latter div has too many sub-divs (it overflows the height of the screen), it appears under the former div instead of next to it, but this works fine if it does not overflow.

Here is the relevant HTML and CSS code:

```css
#projects {
  display: inline-block;
}

#project-title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 100px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'JetBrains Mono Regular', monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#project {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.8);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 45%;
}

#project:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <a class="barlinks" href="{{url_for('home')}}" rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</a>
  <a class="barlinks" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">Blog</a>
  <a class="barlinks" href="" rel="noopener noreferrer">Projects</a>
</div>

<div id="left">
  <div id="intro">
    <h1 id="project-title">
      Projects
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="projects">
  {% for project in all_projects %}
  <a href="">
    <div id="project">
      <h2>
        {{project[0]}}
      </h2>
      <p id="project-desc">
        {{project[1]}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note: there is also Flask code, but this simply fills up the aforementioned sub-divs with text.

Here is how I would like the page to look:
[image]

Comment: can't you just use `display: flex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try applying "display: flex" to achieve this.

Here's an example; Add the following CSS to your existing CSS code:

```css
    .columns {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        margin-left: -.4rem;
        margin-right: -.4rem;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-left: .4rem;
        padding-right: .4rem;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

Then wrap the 2 divs with a div with class "columns". And add "column" class to the 2 divs. Like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "bar">
            <a class = "barlinks" href = "{{url_for('home')}}"  rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</a>
            <a class = "barlinks" href = ""  rel="noopener noreferrer">Blog</a>
            <a class = "barlinks" href=""  rel="noopener noreferrer">Projects</a>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div id = "left" class="column">
                <div id = "intro">
                    <h1 id = "project-title">
                        Projects
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "projects column">
                {% for project in all_projects %}
                    <a href = "">
                        <div id = "project">
                            <h2>
                                {{project[0]}}
                            </h2>
                            <p id = "project-desc">
                                {{project[1]}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, remove "width: 45%;" from your css code to see the results better.